# Displaying 'Please fill out this field' for all empty and required fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation

Is it possible to have a HTML/PHP page display multiple instances of the default 'Please fill out this field' message? As in, right next to / underneath every required field which is empty on ***attempted submission***. Solutions with JavaScript or jQuery are preferred.

The input elements already have the `required` attribute, and the first of them which is unfilled is accompanied by the default validation message.

Example of the desired outcome can be seen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6XjV9.jpg)

To be perfectly honest, I find no sense in this, but one of our clients was pretty adamant with this request.

Comment: Try [`required`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_required.asp)

Comment: @prasad Fields are already marked as required. I want to display 'please fill out this field' ***at the same time*** for all unfilled required fields.

Comment: @FiddlingAway required fields will prompt if they are not filled up

Comment: @hungrykoala I know, and I have stated that in the question. What I want to have is the prompt for every single one of them **at the same time**. Please see the screenshot in my question.

Comment: You will need to create your own js validation for this.

Comment: You mean `document.querySelector('#the-form').reportValidity()` ?

Comment: @hungrykoala Ah, OK. I kind of suspected as much, thought didn't want to go into any special coding if there was any other way. Thank you. Please post this an answer, so that I may accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to create your own JS validation for every field and display the necessary response.

This is how I would test if a field is not empty:

```
function checkName(val){
        if(/^[^-\s][\w\s]+$/.test(val)){
            return true;
        }else{
            if(val.length != 0){
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the link you posted showcases the use of `reportValidity`. Bear in mind, it's not supported in some browsers.

```
var formElement = document.querySelector('#the-form');
formElement.reportValidity();
```

Since `reportValidity` might fail (if not implemented in the browser) you could just make a quick and dirty check:

```
if (formElement.reportValidity) //check that the function exists on the form object
    formElement.reportValidity()
```

This relies on the input elements having html5 validation attributes like `<input type="text" minlength=4 required>`.

If you want a more complete validation flow, you will have to write a much more complex piece of software or re-use an existing solution.

Comment: Right, I suspected that solving this would be a needless complication of things already in place. And with various AJAX bits adding and removing elements, it would be even worse. Thanks.