# How to display "Please fill out this field" for all empty and required fields in html form?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation

I have a form as shown in the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/vrn7zx5h/3/ in which I want to show the warning sign "Please fill out this field" **at the same time** for all unfilled required fields.

I found the answer on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46320434/displaying-please-fill-out-this-field-for-all-empty-and-required-fields) (as shown below) but i am not sure how to integrate with the fiddle.

```
function checkName(val){
        if(/^[^-\s][\w\s]+$/.test(val)){
            return true;
        }else{
            if(val.length != 0){
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

**Problem Statement:**

I am wondering what changes I should make in the fiddle so that the above pasted **SO answer** works with the fiddle.

Comment: One thing I must ask, do you not want to use the HTML5 built-in form validator? Do you want some text to appear on the screen? Do you want all errors to be shown at once?

Comment: Yes, I want to display all the errors at once. I am not sure what do you mean by "do you not want to use the HTML5 built-in form validator?"

Comment: There is a built-in form validation in HTML5. Here is a link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Form_validation

Comment: Ok, I am wondering if you can give me a pointer in the fiddle how we can do that.

Comment: @flash the fiddle is already doing that (if by "that" you mean the HTML5 built-in validator)

Comment: My fiddle is not doing it.  I want to show the warning sign "Please fill out this field" at the **same time** for all unfilled required fields.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a JS fiddle that will show all error at one time. It is just barebone and not fancy. You'll need to make it fancy on your own. I also disabled the built-in validator as well with `novalidate` in the form tag.
https://jsfiddle.net/6kxc9hmq/1/
FYI: I also did not put in the functionality to hide the error message on next run, if the input now satisfies the condition.

Basically, I attached a submit event handler to the form and if the validator returned false, I told the form to not submit. Works only on IE9+ (I think) all the other browsers are usually fine with this method. The validator is basically just checking if the value of the input met the condition that I specified.

```
document.getElementById('form').addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
if(!validate())
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it should look like this, if I understand what you mean

```
<form action="">
    Username: <input type="text" name="usrname">
    Password: <input type="password" name="Password">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
<p><strong>Note:</strong> The required attribute of the input tag is not
supported in Internet Explorer 9 and earlier versions.</p>
<script>
    // append the listeners
    document.forms[0].addEventListener('submit', function(evt){
        if([
            checkName(this.querySelector('[name="usrname"')),
            checkName(this.querySelector('[name="Password"'))
        ].some((v)=>v)) {
            evt.preventDefault()
        }
    })

    // check is empty, then notify
    function checkName(element){
        // if you just have to check if is empty, this is enough
        if(element.value) {
            return
        }
        notify(element)
        return true
    }

    // print the message
    function notify(element) {
        if(element.nextElementSibling.classList.contains('notify')) {
            return;
        }
        element.parentNode.insertBefore(
            Object.assign(document.createElement('p'),
            {
                className: 'notify',
                innerHTML: 'Please fill out this field for all empty and required fields'
            }
        ), element.nextSibling)
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your form, add empty divs after each input element. And you can conditionally display messages in the div in your validation.  E.g if(name ==‘ ‘){div.innerHTML = ‘please enter your name’}

Answer (score -1):

The required Attribute
Add the required attribute to your form.

The required attribute tells the browser to only submit the form if the field in question is filled out. Obviously, this means that the field can’t be left empty, but it also means that, depending on other attributes or the field’s type, only certain types of values will be accepted.